# select random row from MS access table

Tags: c#, ms-access

i want display 1 record from colums `zodys`, I'm programint in C#

I have table `test` and I want select row `zodys`

```
SELECT top 1 zodys from test ORDER BY rnd(zodys)
```

I get error: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly being without the ability to test, but `Rnd` in Access queries takes a numeric parameter, so I presume zodys is not numeric.

[Here's an entire article on the subject of random sorting in Access.](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/random_query.html)

Comment: Thanks I will use this `SELECT top 1 zodys from test ORDER BY Rnd(-(6*ID)*time());`

Comment: Updated the answer with a better reference.

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of [zodys]?  If it's text, that is why you're getting "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

If you get that error message with [zodys] as a numeric data type, look at [Rnd Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/rnd-function-HA001228901.aspx) from Microsoft Office documentation for an explanation.